# Read specific excel cell value without loading the whole sheet to dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I know how to read the whole dataset, I know how to read a part of it, but it always reads all of the columns from my excel file. I do it like this:

```
myfile = pd.ExcelFile('my_file.xlsx')
myfile.parse(2, skiprows=14, skipfooter= 2).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

But I can not read only one specific cell this way, because it read the whole row. Is there a way to limit the parser to one column?

**UPDATE:**

*looking for a Pandas solution*

Comment: I think this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480449/reading-particular-cell-value-from-excelsheet-in-python) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309256/get-column-data-by-column-name-and-sheet-name).

Comment: it's not using pandas. I'll update my OP on this

Comment: @milka1117 full column or only cell?

Comment: @Sid I need specific cell in a specific column. Right know I can read all columns on a specific row. But I need one cell

Answer (score 0):

Update your `pandas` to 0.24.2:

Docs: [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), specifically read `usecols`

I believe you will need to use a combination of `skiprows` and `skipfooter` to narrow down to specific row and `usecols` to get the column. This way you will get the specific cells value.